# Kiel oni diras "kafon sen kafeino" unuvorte?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-formation

En aliaj lingvoj necesas nur unu vorton por diri kafon sen kafeino. Ekzemple, en la angla ekzistas *decaf*.

Ĉu estas komunuza fojo por diri kafon sen kafeino per unu vorto? Mi ne povis trovi ĝin en retaj vortaroj.

Comment: _decaf_ can refer to any substance. Cofee and tea are the usual ones. So _decaf_ is not a single word for _decaffinated coffee_, although it is understood that way. In other languages _senkafeina_ works like that too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mi ne pensas, ke ekzistas komunuza vorto por diri tion unuvorte. Se vi volas ion mallongan, mi rekomendus la duvortan esprimon "senkafeina kafo".

Comment: Unuvortaj mallongigoj kiel _decaf_ estas tipaj en la angla sed ne necese en aliaj lingvoj. _Senkafeina kafo_ sonas trafa.

Answer (score -1):

Mi supozas, ke esprimi tion vi povus per vorto kafgustaĵo - la trinkaĵo kun nur gusto de kafo sed sen aliaj ecoj de kafo.